Georeferencer GDAL not in my QGIS version 3.38.2 - Grenoble, any other tips?
I'm using QGIS in version 3.38.2 - Grenoble. I'm trying to georeference a tiff image, however there is no plugin in this version. I've done some searches on add-ons and I can't find it, is there a similar plugin? or another way to georeference?


